# Limiting number of student registering for hostel

Tags: php, jquery, html, phpmyadmin, notepad++

I'm working on my hostel registration systems but I seems to get trouble with limiting the  number of students that can apply for hostel.For example hostel1 only have 100 rooms,what should I do when the 101th person who register will be getting a message saying that hostel1 is already full. I'm using HTML,PHP,CSS and jQuery as the languages for my project

Comment: It's a good idea, 'cuz nobody wants share rooms nowadays.

Comment: how are you storing the registrations?

Comment: @Sean using php into the database under studentinfo table containing stdName,stdId,stdGender,and stdHostel.for hostel,I want to set the limit for number of rooms but don't know how.should I create another table for hostels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assuming you have a database and it stores

`hostel_id, hostel_name, max_rooms, occupied_rooms`

you need to update the `occupied_rooms` field every time someone registers and while registering just ensure that

`max_rooms > occupied_rooms`

You could do the same using arrays as well I suppose.

**EDIT**
Use your database administration tool to add a new table called hostels then fill it with your initial hostel data

or use the the sql command

```
CREATE TABLE database_name.hostels (
INT hostel_id NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
VARCHAR(50) hostel_name NOT NULL,
SMALLINT max_rooms NOT NULL DEFAULT 100,
SMALLINT available_rooms NOT NULL DEFAULT 100
)
```

Comment: my idea is using array at first.but someone told me to use 'join' and set the number of row in database and then counter it.it made me confuse

Comment: depends on how big your system is. For a small system even an array would be fine. In fact it would run faster since there would be no database access overhead. However when developing a larger system you can use MySQL as a database and then use a structure similar to the one I have proposed to save your hostel data. More info on php+mysql here -->
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/‎